# update MySql Database with Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Okay, I'm completely lost...

What I am trying to do is update one row in my database.

```
$sizes = array($_POST['size_0'],
               $_POST['size_1'],
               $_POST['size_2'],
               $_POST['size_3'],
               $_POST['size_4']);

$sizes_upd = implode(", ", $sizes);

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE beds 
                    SET `Available Sizes` = '$sizes_upd' " .
                    "WHERE ID = '$prod_id' ");
```

My Problem is that not all of my `$_POST[]` contain data.  So let us say for instance `$sizes[0] && $sizes[1]` contain data, the following string is returned:

`value1, value2, , , ,`

How do I prevent this so that only the `$_POST[]` with data returns a value?

Comment: You should build the query while looping array checking if data is set, also your code is vulnerable to mysql injection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[array_filter](https://www.php.net/array_filter)** to clean up your array,

```
$sizes_upd = implode(", ", array_filter($sizes));
```

Comment: + bobby-tables, oh for the love of the spaghetti monster... sanitize database inserts

Comment: Could you PLS stop stealing all of my answers before i press this damn "Post your Answer" Button? xD Still +1 :P

Comment: @YUNOWORK: May be he is reading your mind in advance you post it.

Comment: I i think so. Im scared now. Time that i start to wear one of these aluminum hats so im protected from mental attacks.

Comment: Awesome! Simple Solution. Thank you!